# Como restringir algumas iterações do BD?

Tags: postgresql

Explicando o titulo:

Tenho uma tabela chamada projetos, esses projetos podem ser aprovados ou reprovados.

Cada inserção ou atualização de um registro na tabela de projetos é guardada em uma tabela de histórico (ex: Gravei um projeto e depois atualizei 2 vezes / Na tabela histórico teremos 3 tuplas).

Normalmente estes são aprovados e reprovados várias vezes, e muito raramente depois de aprovados podem ser reprovados de novo.

**O meu objetivo é fazer uma consulta que mostre somente os ID's que tem a ultima data de cadastro com a situação *reprovado*.**

Ou seja, se eu tenho um projeto que foi reprovado, reprovado e reprovado.

Ele deve aparecer na consulta.

Se ele foi reprovado, aprovado e reprovado.

Ele também deve aparecer na consulta.

Comment: Tem sim, coloque o trecho relevante das suas tabelas, para te auxiliarmos no SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando a tabela

```
idHistorico int PRIMARY AI
idProjeto int 
situacao varchar(255)
```

Basta:

```
SELECT maxh.id, h1.idProjeto
FROM historico_projetos h1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(idHistorico) AS id
    FROM historico_projetos
    GROUP BY idProjeto
    ) maxh 
ON maxh.id = h1.idHistorico AND h1.situacao = 'reprovado'
```

O `SELECT` interno do `INNER JOIN` (`maxh`) retorna o ultimo `idHistorico` de cada projeto (somente uma tupla pois os projetos estão agrupados pelo `GROUP BY`).

A condição do `INNER JOIN` (`ON`) faz a intersecção baseada no último idHistorico (`maxh`) de cada grupo de `idProjeto` com o primeiro select (`h1`).

O Primeiro `SELECT` (`h1`) seleciona todas as linhas da tabela.

Esta interseção (`ON`) seleciona todos as linhas que contem os últimos `idHistorico` (`maxh.id`) e a situação (`h1.situacao = 'reprovado'`) do select (`h1`).

E é devolvida para o código o `maxh.id` (maior `idHistorico` do agrupamento do `idProjeto`) e o `h1.idProjeto`.

É um pouco complicado mesmo, e acredito que talvez tenham outras maneiras de se resolver.

Espero te-lo ajudado. boa sorte.